# How to set the x position of the text in HTML canvas drawn using fillText() or strokeText()?

Tags: html, canvas

Writing like context.fillText("Hello World",10,30) sets the x-position of the top left corner of the text. What should I do to set the mid point of the text at x = 70?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the textAlign property of the context?

```
context.textAlign = "center"
context.fillText("Hello world", 70, 30);
```

see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textAlign